# Desktop application in Java

Tags: java, desktop-application

I want to design a desktop application in Java using Swing. I am using NetBeans for creating the application. The application I am going to build is Point Of Sale. I want to get few suggestions form you experts about how to design a efficient software. As this is desktop application it involves many JFrames etc.. so if I need to display different windows with different information what should I do with the existing window or parent window ?

I am going to start my carrier with this application development so please help me out with your valuable tips. I would appreciate more tips i need to know before start developing an application. Any kind of online resources are also appreciated.. thanks guys!!

Comment: I'd ask this question on the UI stackexchange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually for desktop applications like this one we use a JFrame with a JmenuBar and a JToolbar that lead to either (mainly modal) JFrames. A second option would be to use a JDesktopPane with JInternalPanes.

In both cases the main JFrame will be up.

The  JFrames or JInternalFrames may contain JTabbedPanes if needed and additional Toolbars.

Netbeans is almost a perfect tool for this. Spend some time on prototyping and show the options to your customer. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

The application should open only one window (no gimp-like antipattern :))

Other windows you open inside this window.

Comment: is it a good idea to hide one window and open another window ??

Comment: Not very good idea, user expects the old windows will not close when he opens new, f.g. he starts edit something.

Answer (score 0):

You could take into consideration the [CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) apart from a [Tabbed Pane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html)

If I had some time I would also consider using a platform like [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/)(SWING) or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/platform/)(SWT) and develop my own plugins rather than fighting it off myself to figure out a lot of things that have already been figured out by thousands of people.

Good luck with your start.